# Can I get more information during the "Shutting down..." screen in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Here is my problem:

I have issued Windows 7 to check my drive C: for bad sectors. (Right click on C: -> Properties -> Tools -> Check now... -> Both checkboxed checked -> Start)

It told me that this command cannot be issued at the moment and thus has to be scheduled.

I issued a shutdown for the process to start, but it is stuck in the "Shutting down..." screen. I assume that this means Windows is checking my hard drive and this takes a few hours.

Now to my question: Can I check what Windows is doing in the "Shutting down..." screen? I want to know if there is actual progress and perhaps how long it will take.

Is there some way to switch to some kind of console mode with more information like in Ubuntu. I think the F2 key switched from the startup screen to a console with a log.

Comment: Drive checking runs at startup.. not at shut down. Something get crashed. Do force shut down by pressing power button and hold until 10 seconds..

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately the very drive I wanted to fix crashed on me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to show progress information on screen like Ubuntu , while shutdown process in windows 7.
- If we install drivers or windows updates , we can see the "configuring updates process " and it will ask us to do not shutdown till complete . 
- During shutdown process , windows involves many things like closing application programs , drivers , services , network connections in background .

Comment: There is a way, and I have it activated on one of my systems; as far as I remember using a registry key. Unfortunately, I forgot which one! In fact I'm just creating a new question to find out =)